# Why is the source struct being modified according to the copy?

Tags: c++, struct

So I got puzzles with the following format:

```
1 2 3 
4 x 5 
6 7 8
```

In this function I move 'x' around, generating 4 possible variations, each of them having 'x' exchange positions with one of its neighbors.

The problem is: every time I modify one of the copies the original struct is modified as well, so the next variations accumulate the previous x's.
By the end of the function, `current` is:

```
1 x 3 
x 7 x 
6 x 8
```

(the first change is actually correct, that's why the middle 'x' disappears)

My code:

```
struct state{
    char** puzzle;
    // (...) 
    bool valid;
    int xi; // x's row
    int xj; // x's column
};

void next_states(state current, state next[4]){
    next[0] = current;
    next[1] = current;
    next[2] = current;
    next[3] = current;

    if(current.xj-1>=0){ // moves 'x' left
        next[0].puzzle[current.xi][current.xj] = current.puzzle[current.xi][current.xj-1];
        next[0].puzzle[current.xi][current.xj-1] = 'x';
        --next[0].xj;
    } else {
        next[0].valid = false;
    }

    if(current.xj+1<3){ // moves 'x' right
        next[1].puzzle[current.xi][current.xj] = current.puzzle[current.xi][current.xj+1];
        next[1].puzzle[current.xi][current.xj+1] = 'x';
        ++next[1].xj;
    } else {
        next[1].valid = false;
    }
    if(current.xi-1>=0){
        next[2].puzzle[current.xi][current.xj] = current.puzzle[current.xi-1][current.xj];
        next[2].puzzle[current.xi-1][current.xj] = 'x';
        --next[2].xi;
    } else {
        next[2].valid = false;
    }
    if(current.xi+1<3){ // moves 'x'down
        next[3].puzzle[current.xi][current.xj] = current.puzzle[current.xi+1][current.xj];
        next[3].puzzle[current.xi+1][current.xj] = 'x';
        ++next[3].xi;
    } else {
        next[3].valid = false;
    }

    print(current.puzzle); // ERROR: accumulating all the changes above
}
```

Comment: Does you class have a proper copy constructor and copy assignment operator?

Comment: Note: If you think `char **` is a 2D array, you are wrong. It is none and cannot be used as one. Use a 2D array instead.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages! Pick the one you actually use and remove the wrong tag!

Comment: You're doing a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: @Olaf What do you mean? What is it so?

Comment: What is not to be understood about my comment? You might want to take the [tour]. Anyway, as you accepted a C++ answer, I've removed the C tag myself. Next time don't add the wrong tag!

Comment: I meant the `char**` vs `std::array` comment. But thanks for editing anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the member `char** puzzle` of your `struct`.

You are copying `state` by value inside `next[4]` which makes sense but the `struct` contains a pointer object.

This means that, without a proper [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), the value of `puzzle` will be copied to all `state` created thus sharing the same pointer to the same memory.

This is clearly not what you need, but since you are working with an array of fixed size why don't you use something more suitable that will be copied correctly by value without sharing anything, for example an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
struct state {
  std::array<std::array<char, 3>, 3> puzzle;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jack! 
PS: It's missing a comma after  `array<char, 3>`